# How to obtain documents which don't contain object with specific value inside an array

Tags: couchbase, nickel

For example, I have two documents:

```
{
  communication: "some data 1"
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Peter',
      role: 'admin'
      gender: 'male'
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      role: 'guest'
      gender: 'male'
    }
  ]
}


{
  communication: "some data 2"
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Kollins',
      role: 'admin'
      gender: 'male'
    },
    {
      name: 'Steve',
      role: 'moderator'
      gender: 'male'
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, I have to obtain documents that don't have inside a `users` array the `user` with `role: 'guest'`. Basing on the example of two documents I have to obtain the second one.
Pseudo code is like:
`select * from bucket where users.role = 'guest' is missing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the users array with [`ARRAY`](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#story-h2-3) and check if there is a user with [`NOT EXISTS`](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#story-h2-5)

```
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE NOT EXISTS ARRAY users FOR user IN users 
WHEN user.role='guest' END
```